# Unable to format the output of a link in python

Tags: python

I am trying to access weather api data. It returns a long a less human readable single line. I am trying to replace every bracket({) with '{/n' so that bracket remains but as well a new line character just for better readable json.
But it returns every character on a new line in the shell.

```
import urllib2

url2 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=london,PK&units=metric'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url2)
s = data.read()
count = 0
s = s.replace('{',"{\n")
#s = ''.join(s)
for line in s:
    print line
    count = count + 1
print count
```

after join() the problem still persists.
The problematic output after this code is like this[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the built-in capabilities of the json library that's standard in Python?

```
import urllib2
import json

url2 = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=london,PK&units=metric'
data = urllib2.urlopen(url2)

# read the contents in and parse the JSON.
jsonData = json.loads(data.read())

# print it out nicely formatted:
print json.dumps(jsonData, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

output:

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "count": 1,
    "list": [
        {
            "clouds": {
                "all": 20
            },
            "coord": {
                "lat": 38.7994,
                "lon": -89.9603
            },
            "dt": 1442072098,
            "id": 4237717,
            "main": {
                "humidity": 67,
                "pressure": 1020,
                "temp": 16.82,
                "temp_max": 18.89,
                "temp_min": 15
            },
            "name": "Edwardsville",
            "sys": {
                "country": "United States of America"
            },
            "weather": [
                {
                    "description": "few clouds",
                    "icon": "02d",
                    "id": 801,
                    "main": "Clouds"
                }
            ],
            "wind": {
                "deg": 350,
                "speed": 4.6
            }
        }
    ],
    "message": "accurate"
}
```

Comment: Thats what I was trying to do. Print it nicely formatted.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is here:

```
for line in s:
    print line
```

At this point, it will print every character on a separate line - that's what print does (it adds a trailing newline to each print command), as shown by this code:

```
print 1
print
print 2
```

which outputs this:

```
1

2
```

You may be confused with the name `line`, but it's not a special variable name. You can change the word line to any valid variable name and it will work the same way.

A for loop will iterate over an iterable. If it's a file, it will do each line. A list will be each element, and a string goes over every character. Because you say to print it, it then prints them individually.

Are you expecting a non-string response from the API? If it gives a list like this:

```
["calls=10","message=hello"]
```

then your for loop will print each in turn. But if it's just a string, like `"message=hello"` it will print each character.

---

And the reason there is a blank newline after the `{`? Because the `replace` command is working fine.

Comment: removing for and just using a single 'print s' statement solved this. great. I am new to python.

Comment: @UmerTahir if this helped, please remember to click the grey tick below the down arrow, at the side! It will mark this question as solved.

Comment: As i upvoted your answer before. My next vote was awaiting in line for a minute. I am new to stackoverflow as well they don't let me vote quickly. So now I am able to check it.

Answer (score 1):

`s` is just a string, so doing `for x in s` actually iterates over individual characters of `s`, not over its lines. I think you're confusing it with `for line in f` when `f` is a file object!